# SQL database on Visual Studio server error when publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I have created a website on visual studio and I have added an SQL database onto it. I am using DetailsView and GridView to display the data. It works perfectly before I published the website using GoDaddy. I am assuming there is some security issue I need to fix. Any suggestions or help would be great. Thank you.

**Here is the error:**

Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: App_Web_lfy0dq0l.0.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:

Comment: is it a windows server? if so, check the event viewer to find what exactly is going wrong. Also, don't provide screenshots of errros, provide the actual text as it makes it easier to copy/paste

Comment: Yes, I think I found the event viewer but I do not know how to use it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: follow the instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I added <trust level="Full"> and it worked @user1666620

Answer (score 0):

If you are not make sure you are running Visual Studio as Administrator. I'm getting this from the application line in your comment.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

*Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.*

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I do not have level 50 yet. :(